# Vector CANoe error while running the config file

Tags: canoe, tippecanoe

I am getting Rx error while running the configuration file for CANoe.I am not understanding the reason behine this.
Vector CANoe which supports Ethernet.
I am pasting the actual[image] error.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: How does your setup for the CAN bus look like? Is there any other participant acknowledging the CAN packages?

Comment: nope.I am using the config file to simulate the ECMs.I am using only single CAN bus

Comment: The error message looks as if the Bitrate is not set up correctly. However I wonder why you are using the real bus at all when you are simulating alle ECUs.